# Private or Draft status posts in Wordpress are still visible to public?

Tags: wordpress, post, status

I have set my posts page to both private and draft statuses, but whatever I do I can still access it when not logged in! I have tried all browsers/clearing cache/deactivating all caching plugins etc. I am also just using the standard WordPress query & loop ... Does anyone know why else this might happen?

Answer (score 0):

Update:

Someone helped me to solve this issue. She spotted 2 issues. According to her "The issue was with the `mu-plugins` installed in the file manager and also the `.htaccess`"

The `.htaccess` was renamed as `.htaccess_old` (I figured out it was created by **nitropack** plugin). She reset the `.htaccess` file to its default values but didn't delete the old .htaccess file she just renamed it `.htaccess_old`. If ever needed in future.

It's a helpful article on how you can reset `.htaccess` or create a new one.
https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/wordpress/reset-the-htaccess-file-to-troubleshoot-wordpress-php-errors/

Secondly, she manually deactivated and reactivated the plugins from the Wordpress dashboard. And just after that, everything is working perfectly. (Another plugin she pointed out that was causing the problem in my case was `elementor-safe-mode.php`)

Please thumbs up, if it helps you :)